# how to do hex offset calculation in assembly

Tags: assembly, hex, offset

To my understanding, 0x11(sp) means current memory location of sp plus 11.
for example, if current memory address of sp is at 43ec, 0x11(sp) means 43ec+11=43fd. But when i count from the memory dump, its actually at offset 17. Could anyone please explain this to me. isnt 0x11(sp) means offset 11 of sp?

```
assembly code:
4574:  b012 f845      call  #0x45f8 <puts>
4578:  f190 3800 1100 cmp.b #0x38, 0x11(sp)
457e:  0624           jeq   #0x458c <login+0x60>

memeory dump:
                                      sp
43e0:   0300 1c46 0000 0a00 0000 7845 4141 4141   ...F......xEAAAA
43f0:   4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4138 0044   AAAAAAAAAAAAA8.D
                                        sp+11
```

Comment: 11 hex is 17 decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
```

Hexadecimal:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  A  B  C  D  E  F 10 11 ...
```